# PyQtGraph Axis Not Respecting setPreferredSize()?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to adjust the width of a number of pyqtgraph.AxisItem objects, and on creation I try and set the preferredWidth, to recall it later, it was not recalling the value I had previously set.  Eventually I figured out that the value I was trying to set did not seem to be accepted at all.

I noticed this behavior not just with the preferredSizes but with MinimumSizes as well

Here is the most basic code that I could generate to duplicate the issue:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore


class plotWidget(pg.GraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = pg.GraphicsLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.layout)

        self.main_plot = pg.PlotItem()
        ax = self.main_plot.getAxis('left')
        new_min_width = 100
        ax.setMinimumWidth(new_min_width)
        self.layout.addItem(self.main_plot)
        # assert test will fail
        assert ax.minimumWidth() == new_min_width



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.mkQApp()
    win = plotWidget()

    win.show()
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.